# How do you activate mycryp and mod_rewrite from .htaccess?

Tags: php, htaccess

My hosting provider has the option to modify the PHP configuration with the following code in *.htaccess*:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
```

I would like to know how to activate the extension mcryp and mod_rewrite using something similar to this option that they give me for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once added the mod_rewrite rule in .htaccess it works regular as active , so you can add and use it . You can also ask your hosting company to enable mod rewrite rule for you in server that is much better for you